# I want to get many to many mapping relationship using VBA for the given example below

Tags: vba, excel

Input 1:

```
RICEFW ID   RTM ID
1   1
2   1
3   1
3   2
4   2
4   3
```

Input 2:

```
RTM ID  DT ID
1   1
2   2
3   2
1   4
3   4
```

Output would be something like:

```
RICEFW ID   RTM ID  DT ID
1   1   1
1   1   4
2   1   1
2   1   4
3   1   1
3   1   4
3   2   2
4   2   2
4   3   2
4   3   4
```

the order of the rows doesn’t have to be the same, but there ought to be the 10 different RICEFW/RTM/DT combinations.
I am new to VBA your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ADO with Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819).

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Integer

    ''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
    ''you want, but it is very convenient for notes
    ''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

    strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    ''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
    ''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
    ''can be used.
    ''
    ''This is the ACE connection string, you can get more
    ''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    ''Late binding, so no reference is needed

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

    ''Sheet or range, or named range
    strSQL = "SELECT a.[RICEFW ID], a.[RTM ID], b.[DT ID]" _
       & "FROM [Sheet5$A1:D7] a INNER JOIN [Sheet5$D1:E6] b " _
       & "ON a.[RTM ID] = b.[RTM ID] " _
       & "ORDER BY a.[RICEFW ID], a.[RTM ID]"

    rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

    ''Pick a suitable empty worksheet for the results
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(1, i + 7) = rs(i).Name
    Next

    Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(2, 7).CopyFromRecordset rs

    ''Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you know the name of your workbook as per previous comments? If so, try that: `strFile = "Z:\Docs\ExcelFiles\Book1.xlsm"`. I am very surprised you cannot get the name of an active workbook via VBA.